Collapsible text block which has "Enable Override" option in synced patterns
I am creating a question answer website. Each post has a question( paragraph block) and a solution( collapsible text block).
The idea is that after reading the question, the visitor can click on the collapsed solution to reveal it.
I have created a  synced pattern by going to Appearance->Editor-> Patterns.
Now, when I create a pattern with the 2  blocks mentioned above, there's an option called "Enable override" for the paragraph. This allows me to edit the content of each post's paragraph.
But there's no "Enable override" option for the collapsible text which means that I cannot change the content of each post's collapsible text.
I have tried two different collapsible text blocks so far:
Content Toggle by Ultimate Blocks and
FAQ by Spectra.

Is there any collapsible text block that has "Enable override" option?

Or

Is there some coding that I can do to the existing collapsible text blocks to enable override?

Thanks

The first part of your question is very much a "ask the plugin developers if it's possible?"
The second part, it IS possible and there are probably numerous ways to go about doing so and we'd need to see what you're coding up to be able to suggest a way to do it and help find the actual code solution.
